# Reduce image size in Android Gallery Album view

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, gallery, oneplus-one

On OnePlus One Android version 5.1.1 and Cyanogen 12.1 when I open the Gallery app and select an album the photos in that album appear extremely large. Usually, I would be able to see approx 9-12 photos in the screen however now I see one and half photos. Is there anyway I can change the album view so that I can see multiple photos when I open up an album? I've searched a whole bunch of settings and online but no luck...

Answer (score 1):

You might have changed the DPI from 480 (default) to 560. Keep it up to 520 DPI (go to Settings →  Display & lights).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you may have enlarged the images by zooming in. This is easy to do, also easy to undo. Merely pinch one of your 1 and a half images in the preview panel. This will zoom out to reduce the size of the previews and restore a greater number of simultaneous previews.

Comment: I've tried that multiple times in the preview album pane with no luck unfortunately.